# Finishing twitter bot's automation

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, bots, tweepy

I'm almost done with this bot I just need help automating it's output to go through the tweepy api. I have 3 functions, the first 2 form random sentences from list's, and the third will alternate between the two randomly. My problem is having the third function's output print to my twitter bot, i'm assuming you use `api.update_status()` as well as`sleep` to automate it but even after reading through the docs I'm not sure how to use them with my functions.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import random
import tweepy
from time import sleep
from credentials import *

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)


def sentence_type():

words = [["sentence1","sentence2","sentence3"],
        ["conjunction1","conjunction2","conjunction3"],
        ["sentence1, sentence2, sentence3],
        ["sentence1, sentence2, sentence3"]]


print( ' '.join([random.choice(w) for w in words]))


def sentence_type_2():

words = [["sentence1","sentence2","sentence3"],
        ["conjunction1","conjunction2","conjunction3"],
        ["sentence1, sentence2, sentence3],
        ["sentence1, sentence2, sentence3"]]



print( ' '.join([random.choice(w) for w in words]))




def get_Sentence():
num = random.randrange(1, 3)
if num == 1:
    sentence_type()
elif num == 2:
    sentence_type_2()
```

get_Sentence()

Answer (score 0):

I am not very aware of your problem, I just see this api is able to send the message, you just need to randomly get the message back through this api can go to the specified user

API.send_direct_message(user/screen_name/user_id, text)

Sends a new direct message to the specified user from the authenticating user.

Parameters:

```
1: user – The ID or screen name of the recipient user.

2: screen_name – screen name of the recipient user

3: user_id – user id of the recipient user
```

Return type: DirectMessage object

Comment: so would I just plug my info into this and paste it somewhere into my code? my main problem is being unable to update the bot's status with my functions output, would formatting this soewhere allow my to automate output?